# undefined method error with weird class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error, actionview

If everything is an object/class in ruby, why can't ruby tell me the name of a class/object that causes an error.

```
undefined method `changed_servings?' for #<#<Class:0x00000009a4fa70>:0x00000009814558>):
```

I want to know what `<Class:0x00000009a4fa70>:0x00000009814558>` means basically...

Comment: Show us the code that is causing this error.

Comment: This is generally raised from some dynamically created class using `Class.new`, and without binding the class to some constant (naming the class).

Answer (score 2):

Normally, Ruby will give the name of the Class that the missing method is from. For example if I'm in irb and I create, instantiate, and then call a missing method, Ruby will give me more details than Rails.

```
class Widget
  def initialize
   @widget = 42
  end
end
```

Then I instantiate the class:

```
test = Widget.new
```

I get back the ID of the newly made Object and the Class Name:

```
#<Widget:0x007f850982f560 @widget=42>
```

And if I call a method that is not part of the Widget:

```
test.no_method
```

I get a nice message from irb:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `no_method' for #<Widget:0x007f850982f560 @widget=42>
```

But Back to Rails...I'm not sure specifically why, maybe because of how the Rails MVC is architectured, the actual names of the Classes have been left out, and only the Object ID's are given in the error message.

If I have made a movie app, and I'm in the app/views/model/show.html.erb and I call a method that does not exist like:

```
<% no_method %>
```

My app will explode, with the following message:

```
undefined local variable or method `no_method' for #<#<Class:0x007fb9a51553b8>:0x007fb9a4951c48>
```

I'll wager a bet that the first ID is tied to the Object's Model ID and the second is the Object's View ID, but I'm totally guessing about that. But it's the information above that message that will give you the file path that the error came from, in my case, just above the undefined method error message is:

```
NoMethodError in Movies#index
```

At any rate, you could also do a search in your View templates for that breaking method and you should find it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we write the following.

```
class C
end

C.class_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `class_method' for C:Class
c = C.new
  #=> #<C:0x007fe12bd1eb10> 
c.instance_method
  # NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_method' for #<C:0x007fe12bd1eb10>
```

No surprises there. Now let's do the same but create an *anonymous* class dynamically.

```
klass = Class.new
  #=> #<Class:0x007fe12bce5720> 
klass.class_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `class_method' for #<Class:0x007fe12bce5720>
k = klass.new
  #=> #<#<Class:0x007fe12bce5720>:0x007fe12bcc4fc0> 
k.instance_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_method' for
  #   #<#<Class:0x007fe12bce5720>:0x007fe12bcc4fc0>
```

There you have it!

Incidentally, you can create a class dynamically and assign it a name thusly:

```
Object.const_set 'C', Class.new
  #=> C
```

So now you could write

```
C.class_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `class_method' for C:Class
C.new.instance_method
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_method' for #<C:0x007fe12bc766e0>
```